# Can't connect to Postgres remotely due to "no pg_hba.conf entry for host"

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

**EDIT:** Original question was about connecting.

Thanks to the comments, I was notified I had to add firewall rule. I did:

`sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp`

Now I get a different error `FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[my_ip]"`

Now sure why if I allowed all in that file?

---

ORIGINAL:

I have a postgresql database set up on my digital ocean droplet running ubuntu 18.

I'd like to connect to it inside PGAdmin 4.

I've edited `postgressql.conf`:

`listen_addresses = '*'`

and I've edited `pg_hba.conf`:

`host    all             all             ::/0                    md5`

then i ran `sudo service postgresql restart`

Inside PGAdmin, I still get this error:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "[redacted]" ([redacted]) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

the conf file says it's `5432`

Comment: Any firewalls active on the database host?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll try to figure that out

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when I do `sudo ufw status verbose` it shows 22/tcp and 80/tcp (and the v6 parts) with action `ALLOW IN`. Should 5432 be in there?

Comment: You have to open 5432 in your ufw.

Comment: thanks, guys. now i'm getting a different error `FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[my_ip]"`. my `pg_hba.conf` has `::/0 ` though. And I haven't seen any examples of people putting their computer IP in that file. any advice?

Comment: You are probably connecting with an IPv4, not IPv6

Comment: I do not know how to remedy that.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You can ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and have it resolved there.

Comment: Have you restarted your postgresql server to update the access information on pg_hba.conf? It seems that your instruction are not allowing yet connections from all hosts

Comment: thanks everyone. I replaced `::/0` with `0.0.0.0/0` and now I'm able to connect

Answer (score 1):

I replaced this addition to the `pg_hca.conf` file:

`host all all ::/0 md5`

With

`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

And i'm not able to connect with PGAdmin 4